# How to have JSON data as string as environment variable?

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to figure out a way to include a JSON string as an environment variable in the `serverless.yml` file.

As the env variable will then be parsed as in `JSON.parse(process.env.FOOBAR)`, I've attempted to pass it as a string but seems to break the YAML syntax

```yaml
config:
  FOOBAR: ${env:FOOBAR, '{ "xxxx": "yyyy" }' }
```

Some alternative I might think of is to use the `file()`

```yaml
config:
  FOOBAR: ${env:FOOBAR, file(foobar.json) }
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the correct syntax is:

```yaml
config:
  FOOBAR: ${env:FOOBAR, '{ \"xxxx\": \"yyy\", \"bar\": \"rab\" }'}
```